# Audio duration NaN on certain page request action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

I have been trying to create my custom media player using HTML5 and Jquery.

I have followed different approaches and ran into some trouble based on my way of refreshing the page.

**First Case**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    duration = Math.ceil($('audio')[0].duration);
    $('#duration').html(duration);
});
```

In this case, the duration returns NaN when I redirect the page to the same URL by pressing the `ENTER` key in the address bar. However, it works completely fine when I refresh using the `reload button` or by pressing the `F5` button.

**Second Case**

I read in some answers that loading duration after the `loadedmetadata`event might help. So I tried the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('audio').on('loadedmetadata', function(){
        duration = Math.ceil($('audio')[0].duration);
        $('#duration').html(duration);
    });
});
```

Surprisingly, in this case, the inverse of the first case happened. The duration gets displayed completely fine in the case of a redirect, i.e., pressing `ENTER` while in the address bar. However, in the case of refreshing using the `F5` button or the `reload button`, the duration doesn't get displayed at all, not even NaN which led me to believe that the code doesn't get executed at all.

---

Further reading suggested this might be a bug within the webkit browsers but I  couldn't find anything conclusive or helpful.

What could be the cause behind this peculiar behavior? 
It'd be great if you could explain it along with the solution to this problem.

Edit:
I am mainly looking for an explanation behind this difference in behavior. I would like to understand the mechanism behind rendering a page in the case of redirect and refresh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the problem is that the event handler is set too late, i.e. the audio file has loaded its metadata before the document is even ready.

Try setting the event handler as soon as possible by removing the `$(document).ready` call:

```
$('audio').on('loadedmetadata', function(){
    duration = Math.ceil($('audio')[0].duration);
    $('#duration').html(duration);
});
```

Note that this requires that the `<script>` tag be after the `<audio>` tag in the document.

Alternatively, you can tweak your logic slightly, so that the code that updates the duration always runs (but fails gracefully if it gets a `NaN`):

```
function updateDuration() {
    var duration = Math.ceil($('audio')[0].duration);
    if (duration)
        $('#duration').html(duration);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('audio').on('loadedmetadata', updateDuration);
    updateDuration();
});
```

Comment: I'll give it a try and get back to you.

Comment: Nope. It still doesn't work. The most peculiar thing is the way it behaves differently in the case of redirect as compared to refreshing the page. What's the difference between the either in terms of page loading sequence?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it three different cases now. 

Hard reload and reload both return the same behavior.

Comment: Still, what boggles me the most is the difference in behavior in case of redirect and refresh. Could you maybe explain to me the mechanism of rendering the page in each case?

Answer (score 2):

Lovely code examples and stuff from people - but the explanation is actually very simple.

If the file is already in the cache then the `loadedmetadata` event will not fire (nor will a number of other events - basically because they've already fired by the time you attach your listeners) and the `duration` will be set. If it's not in the cache then the `duration` will be `NaN`, and the event will fire.

The solution is sort of simple.

```
function runWhenLoaded() { /* read duration etc, this = audio element */ }

if (!audio.readyState) { // or $audio[0].readyState
    audio.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", runWhenLoaded);
    // or $audio.on("loadedmetadata", runWhenLoaded);
} else {
    runWhenLoaded.call(audio);
    // or runWhenLoaded.call($audio[0]);
}
```

I've included the jQuery alternatives in the code comments.

Comment: Basically you've got a bunch of code that you want to call when you can play audio, we check if the readyState is any 0 (ie, not even got metadata) - if so then we add the event, if not (there's metadata, or even the whole file) then we call the function directly - using ```.call(this)``` lets us set the ```this``` value to exactly the same as if it was an event - so the code doesn't need to be changed

Comment: I didn't know about the .call() method. +1 for this technique.

Answer (score 0):

According to [w3 spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#loading-the-media-resource) this is standard behavior when duration returns NaN.
So I suggest use `durationchange` event:

```
$('audio').on('durationchange', function(){
    var duration = $('audio')[0].duration;
    if(!isNaN(duration)) {
        $('#duration').html(Math.ceil(duration));
    }
});
```

**NOTE:** This code (and your too) will not work correct in case if you have more than one `audio` element on page. Reason is that you listen events from all `audio` elements on page and each element will fire own event:

```
$('audio').on('durationchange', function(){...});
```

OR

You can try:

```
    <script>
       function durationchange() {
          var duration = $('audio')[0].duration;
          if(!isNaN(duration)) {
              $('#duration').html(Math.ceil(duration));
          }
        }
    </script>

    <audio ondurationchange="durationchange()">
         <source src="test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
```

Comment: I have only one audio file and duration change event returns the same response.

Answer (score 0):

Note that behaviors will differ from one browser to another. On Chrome, you have  different type of loading. When resources are not in `cache`, it will fetch either the complete file (for js or css for example), either a part of the file (mp3 for example). This partial file contains `metadata` that allows browser to determine duration and other data such as the time it'll take to download whole file at this rate, trigerring for example `canplay` or `canplaythrough` events. If you look at network usage in you dev console, you'll see that the `HTTP status code` will be either 200 (succesful load) or 206(partial load - for mp3 for example).

When you hit `refresh`, elements are checked to see if they changed. HTTP status will then be `304`, meaning file hasn't been modified. If it hasn't changed and is still in browser cache, then it won't be downloaded. The call to determine if it has or not changed comes from the server providing the file.

When ou simply click enter in adress bar, it's automatically taken from cache, not validating online. So it's much faster.

So depending on how you call or refresh your page (either simmple enter, refresh or complete refresh without cache), you'll have big differences on the moment you get the `metadata` from your mp3. Between taking the metadata from cache directly vs making a request to a server, the difference can be a few hundreds milliseconds, which is enough to change what data is available at different moment.

That being said, listening to `loadedmetada` should give consistent result. This event is triggered when the data with duration information is loaded, so whatever way the page is loaded, it shouldn't matter if that called is properly made. At this point you have to consider maybe some interference from other elements. What you should do is follow your audio through various events to get exactly where its at at different moments. So in you document ready you could add listeners for different event and see where the problem occurs. Like this:

```
$('audio')[0].addEventListener('loadstart', check_event)
$('audio')[0].addEventListener('loadeddata', check_event)
$('audio')[0].addEventListener('loadedmetadata', check_event)//at this point you should be able to call duration
$('audio')[0].addEventListener('canplay', check_event) //and so on

function check_event(e) {
   console.log(e.target, e.type)
}
```

You'll see that depending on the way you refresh, these events can come at different moments, maybe explaining inconsistencies in your outputs.

Comment: Even in the case of `loadedmetadata` event, there is no difference in the output, I have tested for all the 7 possible events.

Comment: Maybe a problem with the file then? You can add console.log(e.target, e.type, e.target.duration) to get exactly when you can get duration.

Comment: I want to understand why there is a difference between redirect and refresh, is it because one fetches the metadata from the cache while the other doesn't? That's what I am assuming. 
As of now, I have been able to make it work by putting a delay of 1 second in between the different event callbacks, but that isn't the ideal way to go.

Comment: See my answer, you are right that there are differences in the way the file data is fetched depending on the way you refresh. But that's why the event listeners are there, so that your web app works consistently whatever way the browser handles the requests. And it's pretty clear what loadedmetada does: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_loadedmetadata.asp. One thing that didn't come up in the answer, that maybe would change something is play with preload attribute. Try preload=true or preload=metadata. But at this point either you have corrupted file or something is messing the events.